# Comparing against unicode and str

Tags: python

I have this code that is running from a docker container (outside of my control) that is running 'Python 3.x'. Presume args['row'] contains some kind of unicode string value.

```
if isinstance(args['row'], list):
    new_rows = args['row']

elif isinstance(args['row'], dict):
    new_rows = [args['row']]

elif isinstance(args['row'], str):
    if not args['row'].startswith("["):
        args['row'] = "[" + args['row'] + "]"
    new_rows = json.loads(args['row'])
else:
    raise ValueError("Not a list, dict or string: " + str(type(args['row'])))
```

I'm getting the following error with data being passed in:

> Not a list, dict or string: <type 'unicode'>

Without using other imports, e.g. six, what is the best way to fix this? 'unicode' and 'basestring' do not exist. I'm only interested in ensuring if it's any kind of string it enters the final elif, i.e. it is some kind of string.

Comment: Python strings *are* Unicode. What does `args` and more specifically, `args['row']` contain?

Comment: This is from a SAAS platform so all I know is I am entering a string, but unicode is being passed in and the above does not work, i.e. the isinstance is failing.

Comment: Are you sure it's running Python 3?  Py3 doesn't _have_ a type named `unicode`.

Comment: That is what I was wondering because I thought so to and from a standalone python I cannot get it to fail either. But all I know is the SAAS script is being tagged as Python3. Possibly the docker container is overwriting it. In which case, if it is 2.x, how can I do this python version agnostic?

Comment: can't you check the version of the interpreter?

Comment: What SAAS script are you talking about? What does SAAS mean? If it's `Software As A Service` it means nothing at all. Are you using a specific commercial product? An open source application? Something else?

Comment: I mean it's a script uploaded to a SOAR platform that is then ran from a docker container. I simply supply the script and specify I need Python 3.x with a named Docker container. So my question from above, if it is 2.x, how can I code it so it works from Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: And what is SOAR? `specify I need Python 3.x ` seems whatever you're using has a bug then and needs to be fixed. If you ask for Python 3 and get 2, the solution is not to start writing Python 2

Comment: If you can only supply scripts, try `print(sys.version)`

Comment: You aren't using Python 3 if `<type 'unicode'>` is popping up in an error message.

Comment: Ok, i will raise a ticket with them. But in the meantime is there a way to fix the code so it will work with 2 or 3 without failing?

Comment: Something like `elif sys.version_info.major == 2 and isinstance(args['row'], unicode)` should work. If you are using Python 3, then the call to `isinstance` will never occur and you'll avoid the `NameError` from trying to reference the undefined name `unicode`.

Comment: If you *are* using Python 2, then a `unicode` value is essentially the same as a Python 3 `str` value. If you get a Python 2 `str` value, though, you can't immediately tell whether to treat it like a Python 3 `str` or like a Python 3 `bytes` value.

Comment: Thanks, let me check and I'll update. Looking I think you're all correct, how could you specify a Python version separate to a docker instance. I'm thinking that entry was just for the Lint tool or something unrelated to the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the docker instance was in fact 2.7 not 3, despite saying 3 and the comments from question are all correct

- the error only happens in 2.7 not 3 and will work in 3
- something like if sys.version_info.major == 2 and isinstance(args['row'], unicode) fixes it as a check against 2.7 and 3.x